# Stop/start SYSTEMD service on specific SSID

Tags: linux, systemd, nfs

I only connect to my NAS laptop (arch linux) drives via `NFS` on a specific 5G router with a specific `SSID` for example `NASrouter_5G`. When I change the wifi, that happens frequently, to another router for example `NoNasRouter_2G` I want the drives to be unmounted and remounted back when I connect to `NASrouter_5G` again since the file manager freeze if I don't.

In my research I found a [Match] syntax but this only detects the interface name and that is always wifi0, so that doesn't seem to work.
Also the [networkd-dispatcher](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/networkd-dispatcher/) looks promising I just didn't found anything on how to use it.

**So my Question is:**

*How do I do that, preferably with systemd since I mount the drives on startup and after hybernation with systemd and it works fine. But any way is appreciated since I don't want to type `sudo systemctl stop nfs_moun`t or some `alias` every time I change the network.*

The mounting service file contains the following:

```
[jack@jacks ~]$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs_mount.service 
[Unit]
Descritpion=Documents Mount NAS systemctl start nfs_mount
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/jack/nfs_mount.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is systemd unit [predefined conditions](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conditions%20and%20Asserts) that can be used, but any of them match this use case.

Since your service is a **oneshot** one, the service will become inactive once the main process is termintaed. So using **simple** to **daemonize** the service with an **infinite loop** and **wrapping** your nfs_mount.sh script with an IF statement based on the SSID comparison can make it :

```
#!/bin/sh  
while :
do
    sleep 5
    if [ "$(iwgetid -r)" == 'your_ssid' ] ; then 
      # Your code here
    else 
      # If it was not a oneshot service you can make a place here for a code to kill the service
    fi
done
```

So in this way the filesystem is mounted only if your system is connected to a WIFI that matches the wanted SSID.

Comment: Yeah that works, just with the -r flag and the installation of the haskell-iwlib aur package. I edit your answer. 

Will try a multishot solution. thanks

https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools/blob/master/wireless_tools/iwgetid.c

Comment: Great :) Could you make it as resolved  Thanks

Comment: sure it will not work since the service will be trigered on boot or via start stop and also with the oneshot type, the service will switch to inactive state once the main process exit. so if you want to detect changes during the runtime you have to daemonize your service with a simple or forked then use (wpa_supplicant -f) and log the wifi events to a file and then use inotifywait tool that you can also create a service that will exectute inotifywait as a service then check on this log file update you will use a processing tool like grep to get the new ssid then execute the oneshot service man

Comment: With an infinite while loop and simple it works now. Thanks @Reda :) Please approve the edit

Comment: Look a good idea to use an infinite loop just make attention at the memory consumption.

Comment: i will edit the answer with the infinit loop if someone else needs the answer.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't even thinking about using bash :) There for the 5 seconds sleep.  2.71K in hole - think it is tolerable and works fine now! Nice!